# Spring validation @AssertTrue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

How do I display on a view jsp validation error message that occurs as a result of `@AssertTrue` annotation? It isn't tied to a specific field, but I am using it to validate a combination of fields. If I use `<form:errors path="*"/>` that will display all the errors for that form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declaring a boolean property is what seems to work for this. So if there is:

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isConditionTrue() {
   ...
   ...
}
```

then declaring a property like:

```
private boolean conditionTrue;
```

works.

Answer (score 36):

From what I have tested it is important **HOW** you name your test function. And you should name it properly.

**You do not need field, getter or setter but your function HAVE TO start with 'is*' statement.**

fe.

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isConditionTrue() {
   ...
   ...


}
```

or

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isSomethingElseOk() {
   ...
   ...
}
```

---

Though, you need a field and getter/setter if you need to use a error form with path, like:

```
<form:errors path="someFieldToDisplay" />
```

But i think this is quite obvious.

---

### Some schema problem which I didn't step into but might be helpful:

This might be helpful as well:
[lack of error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155767/asserttrue-of-javax-validation-isnt-it-supposed-to-create-an-error-message).

But if you use schema without version tag, it uses the newest version by default.

Comment: Renaming the method from valid() to isValid() fixed it for me with Spring using Hibernate Validation.

Comment: Renaming to is* fixed for me, too. Thanks for the answer. This should be accepted as correct answer.

Comment: This indeed should be the accepted answer. I had no idea about the necessary naming convention

Comment: This is crazy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should name your property like this:

```
@AssertTrue(message = "....")
private boolean conditionTrue; //***NOT isConditionTrue***

public boolean isConditionTrue() {
    return conditionTrue;
}

public void setConditionTrue(boolean conditionTrue) {
    this.conditionTrue= conditionTrue;
}

<form:errors path="*"/> or
<form:errors path="conditionTrue"/>
```

Comment: when message will get display ?