# @AssertTrue of javax.validation - isn't it supposed to create an error message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, bean-validation

I am having the following code in a Spring-MVC command bean:

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isConditionTrue() {
    return false;
}

private boolean conditionTrue;
```

My JSP contains the following:

`<form:errors path="conditionTrue" cssClass="error" />`

I would expect to see some error message in the produced HTML... however I see no error message. What do I miss?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does it work for other annotations?

Comment: Thanks. I just found out what was the problem. I was using a too old version of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc` in my dispatcher-servlet.xml. I now use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd` and `@AssertTrue` works again!

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer to your own question and accept that answer to prevent stackoverflow from displaying this question as unanswered. Thanks!